# C# XML Select Multiple Nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to modify a website that was built by some other web developers.

The part in question, reads an XML data file and pulls back data to display on a Google Map.

They have a line of code;

```
string path = Server.MapPath(OutageXmlVirtualPath); //path to XML file

OutageData outages = XMLUtil.Deserialize<OutageData>(path);

Outage outage = outages.Outages.FirstOrDefault(o => o.PostCodes.Any(p => FoundOutagePostcode(p)) && !o.Planned);
```

That pulls the First record in the XML that matches a postcode the user has entered into a textbox. (lastOrDefault works also)

The issue with this however, is that the postcode they enter might appear more than once. In another node in the XML. So what I want to do is pull back all of the records in the XML that match. Not just the first. I can see that there is 'All' and 'SelectMany' methods, but dont know how to implement these into my code.

I would consider myself a complete novice in this area.

If anyone is able to lend any help that would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Chris

XML sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<OutageData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <TimeStamp>2013-12-16T06:38:00.1706983+00:00</TimeStamp>
  <Outages>
    <Outage>
      <Region>South West</Region>
      <IncidentID>INCD-83651-m</IncidentID>
      <ConfirmedOff>1</ConfirmedOff>
      <PredictedOff>0</PredictedOff>
      <Restored>0</Restored>
      <Status>In Progress</Status>
      <Planned>false</Planned>
      <StartTime>2013-12-14T18:03:00</StartTime>
      <ETR>2013-12-16T12:00:00</ETR>
      <Voltage>LV</Voltage>
      <PostCodes>
        <string>PL1 4RL</string>
        <string>PL2 1AF</string>
        <string>PL2 1AG</string>
        <string>PL2 1AH</string>
      </PostCodes>
      <Sensitive>1</Sensitive>
    </Outage>
    <Outage>
      <Region>West Midlands</Region>
      <IncidentID>INCD-12499-I</IncidentID>
      <ConfirmedOff>0</ConfirmedOff>
      <PredictedOff>0</PredictedOff>
      <Restored>0</Restored>
      <Status>In Progress</Status>
      <Planned>true</Planned>
      <StartTime>2013-12-13T10:00:00</StartTime>
      <ETR xsi:nil="true" />
      <Voltage>HV</Voltage>
      <PostCodes>
        <string>SY7 9AX</string>
        <string>SY7 9AY</string>
        <string>SY7 9AZ</string>
        <string>SY7 9BE</string>
      </PostCodes>
      <Sensitive>0</Sensitive>
    </Outage>
  </Outages>
</OutageData>
```

Answer (score 1):

just try to use `Where`

```
var outagesFound = outages.Outages.Where(o => o.PostCodes.Any(p => FoundOutagePostcode(p)) && !o.Planned);
```

and then you can iterate through the `outagesfound` list using  the `foreach` loop

Comment: `var` is of course an `IEnumerable<Outage>` which you can then do a `foreach` loop around ;)